# What is the best file system (used by an Amazon EBS volume) for a lucene index?

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-ebs, lucene

I want to create an ebs volume (Amazon EC2 cloud computing) to store my lucene index.

What is the best file system to use (when using the command mkfs -t ?) ?
I know xfs is often used for mysql but is it the case for lucene index ?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a comparison of Various Linux filesystems (ext4,btrfs,nilfs2,xfs).

[Phoronix Comparison of FileSystems](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ext4_btrfs_nilfs2&num=1)

Since you require fast reads on the Index

NILFS2 has better random read performance

EXT3 has better multi threaded read performance

EXT4 has better overall performance.

I would say , you should choose between these three.

ps: Surprisingly BTRFS beats XFS in SQL CRUD performance.